# Python another application launch

Tags: python, process

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
script_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
subprocess.Popen(["application.exe"],cwd=script_dir, close_fds=True)
```

My problem is that I cant get the above code working. I am trying to run the `application.exe` with my Python code but nothing happends while running it.

I am running the another application similar way and it works:

```
 subprocess.Popen(["binary\\application.exe"],cwd=os.path.realpath("./binary/"), env=os.environ.copy(), close_fds=True)
```

So the question is, what is wrong with the first subprocess call and how could I fix that?

Comment: Two questions: 1) Does the application work outside of python? 2) I notice in the one that works ou are setting the `env` argument... should you do that for the one that doesn't work as well?

Comment: @SethMMorton 1) Yes, 2) Been trying that with the same results.

Comment: Just BTW, you should not be using backslashes to create paths in python.  Use os.path.join()

Answer (score 1):

Specify the first argument as absolute path using [`os.path.join`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join):

```
script_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
subprocess.Popen(
    [os.path.join(script_dir, "application.exe")],
    cwd=script_dir, close_fds=True)
```